# "Aprire per pranzo" vs "aprire a pranzo"

Tags: meaning, difference, prepositions

Are both sentences below correct and usual?

- Un ristorante apre a pranzo.
- Un ristorante apre per pranzo.

I suppose that the first sentence expresses the time period when the restaurant is open and the second one the motivation of opening it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both sentences can be used to express practically the same meaning (I would say that the difference you pointed out is correct but rarely noticed), but be aware of the fact that they both mean that the restaurant **opens** at lunch time (i.e. it is closed before). If you want to say that a restaurant **is open** at lunch time, I would suggest either one of these sentences:

- Il ristorante è aperto a mezzogiorno.
- Il ristorante è aperto a pranzo.

:)

Answer (score 0):

Ciao,

Non sono un esperto ma penso che la differenza sia questa:

- Il ristorante apre a pranzo.
- Ho aperto una scatola di pomodori per pranzo. (anche se una scatola di pomodori pelati cotti per pranzo forse se li mangia solo un affamato di domenica quando i supermercati sono chiusi e non ha niente che faccia per la sua dieta in casa).

Cioè, uno si riferisce al tempo durante il quale si pranza, e l'altro alle cose che si sono consumate durante il pranzo.